# Optimistic updates for item create in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Can't figure out how to get optimistic updates to work properly when I'm creating a new item rather than updating the existing one.

The optimistic updates do work but if I switch to Offline mode, the `patchResult.undo()` isn't removing the added element.

It would also be nice to have an example of deleting items optimistically

Here is my code

```
        createMessagesItem: builder.mutation<void, Omit<IMessagesItem, '_id'>>({
            query: (payload) => ({
                url: `messages`,
                method: 'POST',
                body: payload,
            }),

            async onQueryStarted(patch, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
                const patchResult = dispatch(
                    storageApi.util.updateQueryData('getMessages', undefined, (draft) => {
                        draft.push({ ...patch, _id: '' });
                    })
                );

                try {
                    await queryFulfilled;
                } catch {
                    patchResult.undo();
                }
            },

            invalidatesTags: ['Messages'],
        }),
```

Comment: Assuming you called `useGetMessagesQuery(undefined)` or `useGetMessagesQuery()`, that should update it's cache entry - as long as it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few error in your code, but can't reproduce for test the "offline" situation.

The main one is that this

```
draft.push({ ...patch, _id: '' });
```

should throw an error:

Property 'push' does not exist on type 'MaybeDrafted'.
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Post'

meaning draft is NOT an array BUT and Object thus you need to

```
Object.assign(draft, patch)
```

in order to change draft attributes accordingly to patch.

Why not go as from the standard implementation as in [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates):

```
updatePost: build.mutation<void, Pick<IMessagesItem, 'id'> & Partial<Post>>({
  query: ({ id, ...patch }) => ({
    url: `posts/${id}`,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: patch,
  }),
  async onQueryStarted({ id, ...patch }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
    const patchResult = dispatch(
      api.util.updateQueryData('getMessage', id, (draft) => {
        Object.assign(draft, patch)
      })
    )
    try {
      await queryFulfilled
    } catch {
      patchResult.undo()
    }
  },
  invalidatesTags: (result, error, { id }) => [{ type: 'Post', id }],
}),
```

this should be the delete query:

```
deletePost: build.mutation<{ success: boolean; id: number }, number>({
  query(id) {
    return {
      url: `posts/${id}`,
      method: 'DELETE',
    }
  },
  invalidatesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: 'IMessagesItem', id }],
}),
```

Comment: Why do we need the `invalidatesTags` in the `updatePost` method? Wouldn't that make RTK re-fetch the data again? What if you do NOT want to re-fetch the data, just add item to the cache?

Comment: No the invalidateTags doesn't let RTK re-fetch. RTK is dealing with manage data in cache. The tag is meant to change the 'tag' attached to that data, telling that the previous is not valid has it changed.